# Public Goods - Voluntary provision

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, public-goods

I am currently reading the book "Microeconomics: Principles and Analysis" by Cowell (2006), page 452-453. e have a two-commodity world, in which there are
${n_h}$ agents (households): commodity 1 is a pure public good and commodity 2 is
purely private.

Each agent has an exogenously given income ${y^h}$ , denominated in units of the
private good 2. We imagine that the public good is to be financed voluntarily,
each household makes a contribution ${z^h}$ which leaves

$$x_2^h = {y^h} - {z^h}$$ of the private good available for h’s own consumption
and
$${x_1} = \phi (\bar z + {y^h} - x_2^h)$$    where z is the total input of the good 2 used in the production process. Each agent realises that the total output of the public good depends upon his
or her own contribution and upon that made by others

---

The expression (13.30)

[image]

The expression (13.31)

[image]

---

[image]

Did he come to expression (13.33) by applying the chain rule as

$$\eqalign{
  & z = U({x_1},x_2^h)  \cr 
  & {x_1} = g({x_2})  \cr 
  & {{dz} \over {d{x_2}}} = {{\partial f} \over {\partial {x_1}}}{{d{x_1}} \over {d{x_2}}} + {{\partial f} \over {\partial {x_2}}}{{d{x_2}} \over {d{x_2}}} = {{\partial f} \over {\partial {x_1}}}{{d{x_1}} \over {d{x_2}}} + {{\partial f} \over {\partial {x_2}}} \cr} $$

since ${x_1}$ is a function of $x_2^h$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$\max_{x_2^h} \quad U^h(\phi(\bar z + y^h - x_2^h), x_2^h)$$

You have to find FOCs by taking the chain rule twice for the first argument. Denote the argument for function $\phi$ as $(\cdot)$.

$$\frac{\partial U^h}{\partial x_2^h} = \frac{\partial U^h}{\partial \phi} \cdot \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_2^h}$$
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_2^h} = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial (\cdot)} \cdot \frac{\partial (\cdot)}{\partial x_2^h}$$
$$\implies \frac{\partial U^h}{\partial x_2^h} = \frac{\partial U^h}{\partial \phi} \cdot \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial (\cdot)} \cdot \frac{\partial (\cdot)}{\partial x_2^h}$$

Thus, letting $U^h_{1,2}$ represent the partial derivative with respect to the first and second arguments of $U^h$ respectively:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial U^h}{\partial x_2^h} & = U_1^h(\phi(\bar z + y^h - x_2^h), x_2^h) \cdot \phi_z(\bar z + y^h - x_2^h) \cdot -1 \\
& + U_2^h(\phi(\bar z + y^h - x_2^h), x_2^h) \cdot 1
\end{align}$$

The second argument in $U$ has no $\phi$, so only chain rule should be applied there.

Comment: isnt that what i did?

Comment: More or less. I'm merely adding some more detail @user10699

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just apply this

[image]

Obviously different values but same principle ?